# AS3 - Setting layer above parent Object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stage, addchild, displayobject

Is it possible to set the visibility of a Child of an object which is a Child of the Stage above the Stage?

For example, if the Overworld is a Child of the Stage, and a PlayerCharacter is also a Child of the Stage, can the Player Character walk behind parts of the Overworld, for example Trees?

Comment: It's not possible. The only way to control display depth is to adjust the display list order. You an always put all your objects in the same parent and use your own sorting algorithm to control the depth appearance over time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
parent.setChildIndex(Overworld, 1)
parent.setChildIndex(PlayerCharacter , 2)
```

If the depth (z order) of the objects is constant I suggest using layers. Adding three sprites on to your stage. Like background, gameobjects and foreground. Saves a lot of trouble.

```
public Sprite foregroundLayer = new Sprite();
public Sprite objectLayer = new Sprite();
public Sprite backgroundLayer = new Sprite();
```

Add them to the stage in your game initialisation in the desired order.

Comment: I have also thought about this, but the problem with this is that the parts that should be in the foreground are dynamically placed on the Overworld, which automatically has to lie on the layer behind the player. For example, the trees that are placed on the Overworld have two parts, a bottom part where the player can be in front of and and a top part that is in front of the player. So, I don't think this would work without completeley seperating the top of the tree from the bottom. But I see this function in so many flash games, there has to be a solution for this. Also,why "parent."setChild?